# How to write a boolean expression which tests a certain condition?

Tags: python

This is a really stupid question, but I'm not too sure how to write boolean expressions which test a certain condition.

In one of my practice tests, this is the question:

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjrz1.png)

So we can't use things like if and else in this question but rather a boolean expression which evaluates to true or false. The code I wrote is:

```
number1 % number2 != 0 and abs(number1 - number2) >= 5
```

But it's wrong. How would I answer this?

Comment: Hint: The problem says something about the sum of the two numbers, but I don't see a `+` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(number1 + number2) % 2 != 0 and abs(number1 - number2) >= 5
```